# System Verilog FSM `next state` does not transition when `present state` value in next state combinatorial logic block transitions - ternary operator

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, hdl, vivado

in my Verilog code, the `ns` value does not get assigned to any of the values in the `next state logic`. As I coded the `next state logic` to assign a value to the `ns` state variable whenever there is a transition in the `ps`.

Here is the FSM code snippet

```
    // State registers
    always@(posedge clk, negedge rst) begin
        if(!rst) ps <= S1;
        else ps <= ns;
    end
    assign present_state = ps;
    assign next_state = ns;
     
     // Next state logic
    always@(ps, start) begin
        case(ps)
            S1: ns = start ? S2 : S1;
            S2: ns = S3;
            S3: ns = S1;
            //default : ns = S1;
        endcase
    end
```

Here is the tb code snippet

```
    initial begin 
        #0 rst = 0; start = 0;
        #2 rst = 1;
        #10 a = 3; b = 4;
        #10 start = 1;
```

Finally the waveform output
[image: fsm_ns_notransition]

My intention is for the `ps <= ns` to seamlessly transtion from `S1` to `S2` to `S3` back to `S1` and so forth, however for some reason despite the `always_comb` next state logic block, the state change of `ps` at t=0, does not assign the `ns` to a valid state ? Resulting in all further `ps <= ns` assignments to be always `'x` states

Is there a flaw in this logic ?

A swift help is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: this looks a bit strange. According to your V95 code fragment the value of ns should have changed soon after ps was updated. There is something else going on and you need to provide the full reproducer. BTW, why don't you use system verilog if you have it in tags.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong, but I think you have an accidentally implied latch from ns to ns. Since you commented out the default, when ps isn't any of {S1, S2, S3}, ns gets latched back into itself. The order these blocks are processed at simulation start can change, so that could be why ns starts out as X.

Since ns starts as X, that explains why that X propegates to ps on the first rising clock edge not in reset; From there, ps won't match (since you used case instead of casex), and both will stay X like you see here.

I think the easiest way to fix this would be make ns not a latch by specifying the default in the case statement.

(Using always_ff and always_comb can let the compiler help warn you about things like this)

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the responses, I have figured out the reason why. Its the ternary operator `()? x:y;` colon, that was not enclosed properly, leading the compiler to wrongly infer that the ternary operator `()? x:y;` colon is the `case ... endcase` colon. I resolved this issue by just using the `if else` statements to avoid ambiguity. I suppose that the ternary operators `()? x:y;` could be use in a `case` statement if properly written and enclosed, but I just went with an `if else` statement to avoid ambiguity.

```
     // Next state logic
    always@(ps, start) begin
        case(ps)
            //S1: begin ns = (start ? S2 : S1); end  // old code
            S1: begin if(start) ns = S2; else ns = S1; end // new code
            S2: ns = S3;
            S3: ns = S4;
            S4: ns = S1;
            //default : ns = S1;
        endcase
    end
```